# Triangular conundrum

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, algebra

Place any three numbers on the vertices of a triangle:

```
         5
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     8-------4
```

Calculate their differences, going one way:

```
         5
        / \
   -3  /   \ -1
      /     \
     8-------4
         4
```

Place another number inside the triangle:

```
         5
        / \
   -3  /   \ -1
      / 15  \
     8-------4
         4
```

Add the centre number to a vertex, and multiply the total by the opposite edge. Do this for each vertex. Add them together.

$(15+5)\times4=80$
$(15+8)\times-1=-23$
$(15+4)\times-3=-57$

$80-23-57=0$

> You got $0$. Why?

Comment: Because math is cool.

Answer (score 7):

> Although weird-looking in hindsight, some elementary maths clearly show why.
>  [image: fig]

Comment: Should be $(d+c)(a-b)$ et cetera

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about that when I started copying that formula :( Fixed, thanks! @DanielMathias